# Error with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

When I try to add references using

```
    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
     \bibliography{mybib2}
```

it is giving error

```
> \bibdata{mybib2}
(./elsarticle-template-paper1.bbl

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{}

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{}

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 1.
! Undefined control sequence.
```

The `.bbl` file was created in Tex studio and is:

```
    @article{dds2016,
  title={Semantics-based },
  author={Das, Yang and Zhang},
  journal={IEEE transactions on information forensics and security},
  volume={11},
  number={2},
  pages={289--302},
  year={2016},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

How can these errors be solved?

Comment: Where does the `\bilbiography` line appear in your source?

Comment: To expand on Joseph's question: `\bibliography` must appear exactly where you want your bibliography to print in the document. In particular it can't come before `\begin{document}`, traditionally it would come near the end of your paper.